How to auto resize the height of textarea element using ReactJS?
How to resize the height of textarea element automatically based on the input?
Add a file into your solution, useAutoSizeTextArea.ts
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
const useAutoSizeTextArea = (id: string,textAreaRef: HTMLTextAreaElement | null,value: string) => {
//this will calculate the height of textArea before DOM paints
useLayoutEffect(() => {const textArea = textAreaRef ? textAreaRef : document.getElementById(id);

if (textArea) {
  //We need to reset the height momentarily to get the correct scrollHeight for the textarea
  textArea.style.height = "0px";
  const scrollHeight = textArea.scrollHeight;
  textArea.style.height = scrollHeight + "px";
}

}, [textAreaRef, id, value]);
};
export default useAutoSizeTextArea;
----------Use the above component in your file where ever required----------
import useAutoSizeTextArea from "./useAutoSizeTextArea";
const App = (props: any) =>{
    const textAreaRef = React.useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
    useAutoSizeTextArea("title-input", textAreaRef.current, value);

return(
<textarea id="txtTPA"
              value={value}
              ref={textAreaRef}></textarea>
);

}
<style>
#textArea{
resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 110px;
}
</style>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is the solution I have provided to dynamically increase the height of a TextArea element in ReactJS Application
